# Empty value when opening one modal after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a web application with Django, JavaScript, JQuery, and ajax. I've been with this problem for two days, and I can't make progress at all, the problem is the following:

I have two modals, in which a form is loaded. If I hit the create button to open the create modal, everything works fine, I can fill in the form, it is submitted and the data is saved to the database. If I give the edit button, the modal is loaded with the form with the data of the object that is being edited, and everything works perfectly. The problem is when I first open the creation modal, close it, and open the edit modal, a very strange thing happens, and that is that the value of an input that I need always returns it to me empty, despite not being empty. Here is the code (what matters, a summary):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#edicion').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            let $tipoActivo = $('#id_tipo_activo');
            console.log($tipoActivo.val());
        });


        $('#creacion').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            let $tipoActivo = $('#id_tipo_activo');
            console.log($tipoActivo.val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I open the create modal first, close it, and then open the edit modal, let $TipoActivo = $('# id_tipo_activo'); it always empty (''), when in reality I see that its value is not empty.

Comment: You *probably* have `<input id="id_tipo_activo"` on *both* modal's forms.  While IDs *must* be unique throughout the document, browsers can handle it to an extent.  Change `let $tipoActivo = $('#id_tipo_activo');` to `let $tipoActivo = $('#id_tipo_activo', this);`  (where `this` is the event modal (== `e`)).   Ideally change your IDs / don't use an id (form's use the `name=`) / use a single dialog / clean up your old dialog if you're loading the dialog's html via ajax (delete the old dialog's html when closing)

Comment: Yes, I had the same id in both modals, but I thought that when I closed one, it was "cleaned". I'm new to JS (I'm learning), and there are things that escape me ... I've tried let $tipoActivo = $ ('#id_tipo_activo', this); and it works ... Thank you so much. I did not understand what was happening and it has become clear to me ... One question, how can I erase the old dialogues when closing? Thank you so much again...

Comment: You'd have to call [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) on the inner modal / form.  Or `.html("")`.   But only if it's loaded via ajax when being displayed, otherwise you'll only be able to use it once.